# What signature for a generic method mapValues(map,mapper)?

Tags: java, generics, inferred-type

I wrote a custom `CollectionUtils` class to compensate for the lack of certain important functional features in Java 8. However, I'm not really versed in complex genericity and I'm not sure of what signature to give to the following method :

```
public static <K,V,N> Map<K,N> mapValues(Map<K,V> map, Function<V,N> mapper) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,mapper.compose(Map.Entry::getValue)));
}
```

It works this way, but not nicely. For example, the followind code does not compile :

```
CollectionUtils.mapValues(
    candidates.stream().collect(groupingBy(x -> x.category)),
    list -> list.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

(error : *category cannot be resolved or is not a field*, of course `category` **is** a field of `Candidate`, but the compiler does not manage to infer the type of `x` here and set it as `Object`), whereas this compiles fine :

```
Map<String,List<Candidate>> map = candidates.stream().collect(groupingBy(x -> x.category));
return CollectionUtils.mapValues(map,list -> list.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Any way to help the compiler to successfully infer the type of the map ?

Comment: Can you post mode code? I tried to reproduce your problem but your first try compiles without errors, I don't get the same error as you. (Using JDK 8u45).

Comment: What is the type of `candidates`? For me it works fine if it's `List<Candidate>`.

Comment: @Jesper It is indeed a `List<Candidate>`. The posted code is minimal I'm afraid, you just need a clss `Candidate` with a public `String` attribute `category`

Comment: What happens if you specify the type of `x` explicitly: `groupingBy((Candidate x) -> x.category)`

Comment: @Jesper yep, it works this way. It is nicer (thanks), but it is not the way I would like it to work. Is it possible to make the compiler infer the type without precising the type of the parameter ?

Comment: I don't know, because I still don't know why you get this error, while I do not - your first piece of code compiles fine for me, also without specifying the type of `x`. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Full code available here : https://github.com/Dicee/algorithmicProblems/tree/master/miscellaneous (ignore the Python code, it has nothing to do with this).

Comment: Looked at your full code. Replaced `groupingBy((Candidate x) -> x.category)` in your method `getRankingPerCategory` by `groupingBy(x -> x.category)`. Still no compile error - I still can't reproduce your error.

Comment: That's right, it compiles fine with Oracle JDK. It does not compile with the Eclipse compiler though. Well, I think this is the answer, thank you :) I'll accept anything you post